# How do I configure the spring boot quickstart for keycloak?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I am trying to set up a basic example spring boot site which uses keycloak for security. I have done the following

- cloned and ran (`gradlew bootRun`) the 'complete' example from https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/ (https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-serving-web-content.git) to verify that it works
- added the following to the project's gradle dependencies:

  ```
  compile("org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-adapter:2.2.1.Final")
  compile("org.keycloak:keycloak-tomcat8-adapter:2.2.1.Final")
  ```
- put the following in config/application.yml:

  ```
  spring:
      profiles: default

  server.port: 8090

  keycloak:
      securityConstraints:
        - securityCollections:
          - name: application section
            authRoles:
                - user
            patterns:
                - /
      realm: stl
      realmKey: MIIBIjANBgkqh[etc...]
      auth-server-url: http://localhost:8280/auth
      ssl-required: none
      resource: example-ui
      credentials:
          secret: a117[etc...]
  ```

With these steps, I believe I've followed all the directions in https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/securing-client-applications-guide/content/v/2.2/topics/oidc/java/spring-boot-adapter.html. But now when I attempt to browse to the application, I get an error. This is what's logged to the console: `No login page was defined for FORM authentication in context []`

What am I missing to complete configuration of this app? From prior experience with earlier versions of other keycloak adapters, I would expect to have to specify an auth method of `KEYCLOAK` somewhere, but I don't know where that would go in spring boot, if indeed it goes anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here but it's only when I upgraded from Spring boot 1.4.0 to 1.4.1.
They have passed version of tomcat to 8.5.4 to 8.5.5. And every request except GET are working, only GET don't work with the message "No login page was defined for FORM authentication in context []" like you said.

Downgrading the version of tomcat did the trick for me :

```
<tomcat.version>8.5.4</tomcat.version>
```

Can someone know what's going on ?